# Mac mini (mid 2011) fan at full speed constantly

Tags: mac, macos, mac-mini

I upgraded my Mac Mini's HDD to a new SSD... Since then the fan has been running at full speed constantly. I placed back the old drive but that did not fix the problem. I also tried using SmcFanControl but that does not work at all.

In addition, I reseated the fan connector just to be sure, still no joy. Can anyone recommend another option?

I'm running Yosemite...

Answer (score 1):

check the thermal sensors. I broke one off of my Mac mini trying to upgrade the HDD and the fan ran at full speed since. I had to replace the Logic Board to fix the problem.

Comment: Replacing the whole logic board just for a single fan speed connector? Was the connector that far-gone that a new one couldn't just be resoldered in its place?

Answer (score 0):

[Reset SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-sa/HT201295)

If that doesn't help use a tool like [Temperature Monitor](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TemperatureMonitor.html) to check the temp sensors. Perhaps one isn't properly plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once, and it turned out (after I took it in) that the temperature sensor was not working correctly. They replaced the relevant hardware and all was well. Since putting back the old drive did not clear the problem, it's worth checking if this may have somehow happened.